# React route <Link To> is not working in maven springboot project

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, react-router

I have created a maven spring boot project with React, when i run the webpack the Link to works perfectly, when i try to run with mvn spring-boot run, it throws an error 404 and page not found,

My client.js,

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Route,Router, browserHistory} from 'react-router';
import Home from './components/Home';
import About from './components/About';

render((
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/Home" component={Home}></Route>
        <Route path="/about" component={About}></Route>
    </Router>

), document.getElementById('reactDiv'));
```

Home component,

```
import React from 'react';

export default class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
            <h2> Home Page </h2>
            <Link to={`/about`} target="_blank"> 
                About
            </Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

About component,

```
import React from 'react';

export default class About extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
            <h2> About Page </h2>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `browserHistory`, which requires additional configuration on the serverside to make it work. Quoting the [API docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#browserhistory):

> `browserHistory` uses the HTML5 History API when available, and falls back to full refreshes otherwise.
>   `browserHistory` requires additional configuration on the server side to serve up URLs, but is the generally preferred solution for modern web pages.

The easiest alternative is using [`hashHistory`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#hashhistory). This will use the hash symbol (`#`) within your URL.